# How to make a proper news post from a database

Tags: php, sql, database

First of all, sorry if the title is unclear. I have no idea how to explain my problem in a title.

Here's the problem:

I'm creating a site and it has to have new posts on the front page. The new articles are stored in a database with separate columns for text and title. Now I'm trying to put the title above the text itself and I get stuck there. I want something to look like:
(for reference)

```
<h2>title from db</h2>

<h4>text</h4>
```

I am wondering how to code this in php. I've looked around a bit but nothing gets close to what I mean.

EDIT: What I have now is a basic sql command that returns the values of my database. I want it to be that the title is posted above the actual post in a separate variable.
Also I have this now:

```
$query=("SELECT nieuws, titel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
$resultaat=mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultaat, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    while(list($key, $value)=each($row))
        {
            echo "$value<br /><hr />";
        }
}
```

Which returns:

```
post 3
hr
title 3
hr
post 2
hr
title 2
hr
post 1
hr
title 1
hr
```

Comment: It sounds like you've written the code to get the articles and display them, but that the positioning isn't working. If so, could you add that code to your question?

Comment: It's very unclear what your problem is. Showing what you've tried will clarify.

Comment: Some use HTML tables, some use DIVs, you just need to visualize how you want your data to show up. Google "query in html table mysql". As for the new articles to show on top, your query will look something like `SELECT something FROM yourtable ORDER BY something ASC`

Comment: Thank you for adding your code. You need to change the way you're processing `$row` - instead of using a second while loop, try accessing `$row['title']` and `$row['post']` - that will let you use each column separately, so you can wrap each in appropriate HTML tags

Comment: @andrewsi How would I need to use them? I tried adding them as `echo"<h2>$row['title']";` but when I do that I'm getting erros.

Comment: @Luminai - something like `echo "<h2>" . $row['title'] . "</h2>"` should work

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=("SELECT nieuws, titel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
$resultaat=mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultaat, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<h2>'. $row['titel'] . '</h2><br><h4>' . $row['nieuws']. '</h4>';
}
```